# How does True Strike interact with Perfect Strike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats

Namely, I'd like to know if the +20 to your next attack roll with *[True Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-strike/)* is applicable to *either* of the *[Perfect Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/perfect-strike-combat/)* rolls, at your discretion, or if you are forced into it applying on the first roll of *Perfect Strike*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## You add it to both

Perfect Strike allows you to roll "your attack roll", the thing *True Strike* modifies, twice; It does not cause you to make two separate attack rolls.  Since it is a single roll rolled twice you get the +20 to both rolls.  In the odd event you roll a critical threat with one of the rolls you *still* add the +20 to the other roll that is now your critical confirmation roll because it starts off as 'your attack roll' then gets used for something else.

Comment: That is... a beefy use of True Strike, then. Especially Zen Archer's tripled roll!

Comment: @royalmurder sort of... You still only hit once, which true strike probably would have let you do anyways.  Assuming True Strike lets you hit on anything but a one, Perfect Strike improves your odds of hitting by 4.75%, or 4.9875% for the Zen Archer.

Comment: I'm thinking more for the times when you _do_ get a critical threat, then you're pretty much also guaranteeing a critical confirmation.
And hey, that last 5% is what you want to avoid! (I have an aggravating tendency to roll 1s when using limited use per day abilities...)

Comment: This is the case for all "reroll" or "roll X times" abilities, you use the same modifiers unless said otherwise.

Comment: @ShadowKras I suspect the confusion arose from *true strike* saying specifically (since 2000!) that it affects *[y]our next **single** attack roll* (emphasis mine), which means the spell could be read *as* saying otherwise!

Comment: @HeyICanChan yeah i thought the same, but checking the combat and magic chapters on the SRD, the "single" keyword is pretty much everywhere. It has no special meaning. The "single" is there so people wouldn't think that they gain a +20 on all interative attacks.

Comment: Some designer missed a chance at a cheap fandom with a greater true strike that did, surely....

Answer (score 8):

Perfect strike states:

> You can roll your attack roll twice and take the higher result.

As such it is still one attack roll that is rolled twice. By that you can roll twice, choose the higher and then add the +20 to the result.

Would it say that you make two attack rolls only the first could gain the bonus but as both die rolls are the same attack roll you can choose.